# Can't copy files in deployee folder vb.net website

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

i have a problem deploying my website. While trying to publish my website vs it creates the folder but doesn't copy files. I never faced this issue before.I didn't change anything in vs

[image]

Any help solving this issue?

Comment: Are you running VS with Admin Privileges ?

Comment: yes, I always run vs with admin priviledges

Comment: Try cleaning solution and retry. What about application pool ?

Comment: i cleaned but the same, it's not working